# Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string' and can't understand why

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to read all exif data from images in php, turn it into a more accessible form and store it in the image's entry in MariaDB.  The database already had records for existing images in but did not have exif data, so I wrote a one-time process using very similar code.  That worked fine.

The specific logic I'm trying to implement now is to pull exif out for new images as they are uploaded.

Now I'm stuck with a syntax error that I don't understand the cause of:
Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string'

Of course `foreach` requires an iterable, but why here does it see `$headers[$section]` as a string?

Been trying all day to puzzle this out, comparing it with the code that worked and with sample data from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php but still stuck.  Thanks for any help.

```
<?php

$file = '../uploads/60db4bd52107d5.12775787_1624984533.jpg';
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

if (!$fp) {
    $error = 'Error: Unable to open image for reading';
    exit;
}

// Attempt to read the exif headers
$headers = exif_read_data($fp, 0, true);
print_r ($headers);                        // <<<<<< shows exif OK

if ($headers = "") {
    echo 'No exif headers';
    exit;
}

$sections = [ "COMPUTED", "FILE", "IFD0", "THUMBNAIL", "EXIF", "INTEROP" ]; // for exif extraction

$exifAll = "{";
foreach ($sections as $section) {
    $exifAll .= '"' . $section . '":{';
    foreach ($headers[$section] as $header => $value) {
//  >>>>>>>? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  <<<<<<< Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string'
        $exifAll .= '"' . $header . '":"' . $value . '",';
    }
    $exifAll .= '},';
}
```

Comment: Classic bug - you need to change if($headers = "") to if($headers == "") - you're assigning, not comparing there.

Comment: Duh! Tunnel vision strikes again.  Thanks a lot Bob.